# Unable to install two packages in one go

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I can install two packages separately, but whenever I try to install them in one go, I get told they have "unmet dependencies".

This is on a *fresh* install of Ubuntu (both trusty and bionic), so shouldn't be in a broken state.

This works (but I really need to install them in one go):

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib -y && apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu -y && echo "Works!
[...]
Works!
```

This fails:

```
apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-multilib -y

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu : Depends: gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu (>= 7.3.0-12~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output from `aptitude`:

```
aptitude install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-multilib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils{a} binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu{a} binutils-common{a} binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu{a} cpp{a} cpp-7{a} 
  cpp-7-aarch64-linux-gnu{a} cpp-aarch64-linux-gnu{a} gcc{a} gcc-7{a} gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu{ab} 
  gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu-base{a} gcc-7-base{a} gcc-7-cross-base{a} gcc-7-multilib{a} gcc-8-cross-base{a} 
  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-multilib{b} lib32asan4{a} lib32atomic1{a} lib32cilkrts5{a} lib32gcc-7-dev{a} 
  lib32gcc1{a} lib32gomp1{a} lib32itm1{a} lib32mpx2{a} lib32quadmath0{a} lib32stdc++6{a} lib32ubsan0{a} libasan4{a} 
  libasan4-arm64-cross{a} libatomic1{a} libatomic1-arm64-cross{a} libbinutils{a} libc-dev-bin{a} 
  libc6-arm64-cross{a} libc6-dev{a} libc6-dev-arm64-cross{a} libc6-dev-i386{a} libc6-dev-x32{a} libc6-i386{a} 
  libc6-x32{a} libcc1-0{a} libcilkrts5{a} libgcc-7-dev{a} libgcc-7-dev-arm64-cross{a} libgcc1-arm64-cross{a} 
  libgomp1{a} libgomp1-arm64-cross{a} libisl19{a} libitm1{a} libitm1-arm64-cross{a} liblsan0{a} 
  liblsan0-arm64-cross{a} libmpc3{a} libmpfr6{a} libmpx2{a} libquadmath0{a} libstdc++6-arm64-cross{a} libtsan0{a} 
  libtsan0-arm64-cross{a} libubsan0{a} libubsan0-arm64-cross{a} libx32asan4{a} libx32atomic1{a} libx32cilkrts5{a} 
  libx32gcc-7-dev{a} libx32gcc1{a} libx32gomp1{a} libx32itm1{a} libx32quadmath0{a} libx32stdc++6{a} libx32ubsan0{a} 
  linux-libc-dev{a} linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross{a} manpages{a} manpages-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 77 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 65.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 267 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-multilib : Conflicts: gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu but 7.3.0-16ubuntu3cross1 is to be installed
 gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu [Not Installed]            
2)     gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu [Not Installed]              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gcc-multilib [Not Installed]                       

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
2)     libc6-dev-i386 recommends gcc-multilib             
3)     libc6-dev-x32 recommends gcc-multilib              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

Comment: Just install it in one command

Comment: You installed `gcc-multilib` first, which *conflicts* with `gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu`. Please edit your question to show us the output of the 'This works' line demonstrating successful completion, because it seems like that should fail for the same reason.

Comment: @Panther That doesn't work (see my question)

Comment: @user535733 Done

Comment: File s bug report re missing dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just requesting an impossible situation, as hinted here:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gcc-multilib : Conflicts: gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu but 7.3.0-16ubuntu3cross1 is to be installed
 gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

In other words, these packages conflict with each other. You can't install them together. It works if you do both operations independently because the second operation will undo the first one.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed conflicts. See also bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-arm64-cross/+bug/1347820